# can I calculate differentiation and integration using PHP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to make an app that calculates some formulas..and integration and differentiation may be included in this app, alongside other major math stuff. I wanted to know, is it possible to make this application in PHP or JAVASCRIPT?

I hav made a research, even had a look at the PHP MATH functions on PHP.net but nothing suits my question. Thank u!

Comment: so basically create your own math parser/calculator? yes, that's possible. no, there's no pre-built functions that do `calculate($formula)` and give you an answer.

Comment: Okay, so every single function I want to make can be manually built?

Comment: well, php has some basic math functions, like `pow()`, `log()`, etc.. but you can't just feed some arbitrary math "string" into them and expect to get an answer out of them.

Comment: When it comes to polynomial functions rules are easily implemented. Integration and differentiation are just adjusts in the coefficients of the right vector. As to other kind of functions, like trigonometric ones, things are not so easy. But yes, it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, let's see how it goes!